# Unexpected behaviour of subtraction in C code

Tags: c, ctypes

I'm having a weird behaviour in my code when subtracting pix0 and pix1, and in the multiplication for the variable ti. For the former, pix0 and pix1 are constant numbers and therefore, subtracting them should be constant. For the latter, it should be an increasing step after each iteration. After running the code, none of them are right. I got:

```
pix0 = 0.000000
pix1 = 10.000000
subst = 10.000000
ti = 0.000000
subst = 10.000000
ti = 0.010000
subst = 9.990000
ti = 0.030000
subst = 9.970000
ti = 0.060000
subst = 9.940000
ti = 0.100000
subst = 9.900000
ti = 0.150000
subst = 9.850000
ti = 0.210000
subst = 9.790000
ti = 0.280000
subst = 9.720000
ti = 0.360000
subst = 9.640000
ti = 0.450000
subst = 9.550000
```

> Is there anything wrong with the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>

typedef struct {
    double deg_m, deg_p, alpha, alpha_0, beta, n;
} repressilator_params;

int repressilator_func(double t, const double y[], double f[], void *params) {
    (void)(t);
    repressilator_params *p = (repressilator_params *)params;
    double deg_m = p->deg_m;
    double deg_p = p->deg_p;
    double alpha = p->alpha;
    double alpha_0 = p->alpha_0;
    double beta = p->beta;
    double n = p->n;

    f[0] = -deg_m * y[0] + alpha / (1 + pow(y[5], n)) + alpha_0; 
    f[1] = -deg_m * y[1] + alpha / (1 + pow(y[3], n)) + alpha_0; 
    f[2] = -deg_m * y[2] + alpha / (1 + pow(y[4], n)) + alpha_0; 

    f[3] = -deg_p * y[3] + beta * y[0]; 
    f[4] = -deg_p * y[4] + beta * y[1];
    f[5] = -deg_p * y[5] + beta * y[2];

    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}

double* simulate_repressilator(double *params_array, double *initial_conditions, double *time_span, double num_points) {
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {repressilator_func, NULL, 6, params_array};

    double pix0 = time_span[0];
    double pix1 = time_span[1];
    printf("pix0 = %f\n", pix0);
    printf("pix1 = %f\n", pix1);
    double h = 1e-6;
    gsl_odeiv2_driver *d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new(&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rk8pd, h, 1e-8, 0.0);

    double* results = malloc(num_points * 7 * sizeof(double));
    if (!results) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory for results\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    int i;
    double ti;
    int numi = (int) num_points;
    for (i = 0; i < numi; i=i+1) {
        double subst = (pix1 - pix0);
        printf("subst = %f\n", subst);
        ti = pix0 + (10 * ((double) i) / (num_points));
        printf("ti = %f\n", ti);
        
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply(d, &pix0, ti, initial_conditions);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS) {
            printf("Error, return value=%d\n", status);
            free(results);
            return NULL;
        }

        results[i * 7 + 0] = ti;
        results[i * 7 + 1] = initial_conditions[0];
        results[i * 7 + 2] = initial_conditions[1];
        results[i * 7 + 3] = initial_conditions[2];
        results[i * 7 + 4] = initial_conditions[3];
        results[i * 7 + 5] = initial_conditions[4];
        results[i * 7 + 6] = initial_conditions[5];
    }

    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free(d);

    return results;
}
```

Compiling command:

```
gcc -shared -o libRepressilator.so -fPIC repressilator.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
```

Python/ctypes:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

c_lib = ctypes.CDLL('./libRepressilator.so')

c_lib.simulate_repressilator.argtypes = [np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),  # params_array
                                         np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),  # initial_conditions
                                         np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=np.float64, ndim=1, flags="C_CONTIGUOUS"),  # time_span
                                         ctypes.c_double]  # num_points
c_lib.simulate_repressilator.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * 7)


params_array = np.array([1, 0.1, 100, 0.01, 10, 1], dtype=np.float64)  # deg_m, deg_p,alpha, alpha_0, beta, n
initial_conditions = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 3.0], dtype=np.float64)  # m1, m2, m3, p1, p2, p3
time_span = np.array([0, 10], dtype=np.float64)  # Start time, end time
num_points = 1000

result_ptr = c_lib.simulate_repressilator(params_array, initial_conditions, time_span, num_points)


results = np.ctypeslib.as_array(result_ptr.contents, shape=(num_points, 7))

c_lib.free(result_ptr)
```

I tested other sections of the code, and it works ok.

Comment: What is the *expected* output?

Comment: what is value of `num_points` in c? why do you pass `&pix0` to `gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply` - is it to modify it? then your assumption `substracting them should be constant` is wrong. what is `gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I jumped the gun, sorry. I thought I saw the numbers shifting by `0.1 `and then `0.09`, but I was off by a digit.

Comment: Re “pix0 and pix1 are constant numbers”: Why do you think that? Did you print them to check? You pass the address of `pix0` to `gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply`—does that routine change `pix0`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil @Iłya Bursov you were right, ```gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply``` modifies the value of pix0 and that's causing the additional shift. After modifying the code, it's working like a charm! Will upload the modified code soon with the output.